# Software for reading pipermail/mailman listservs (and not feeling its 1991)?

Tags: mac, email, software-recommendation

Does anyone know if there's a piece of Mac (or web?) software that can grab and reformat/organize a good 'ol pipermail/mailman listserv archive, so it a little less infuriating? You know what I'm talking about:

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2019-June

https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2019-June/132794.html

I'd just love to be able to see things organized by thread, be able to collapse portions, have dates and responses listed in the index... it goes on. But basically, like a nice clean email client for reading listservs. Anyone know if anything like that exists?